# On the temple level at the end I lowered the water and found one of the ancient glyphs glow

Tags: journey

On the Temple level I made it to the top and sat in the circle. The story played and then finished. I got up and turned around (faced away from the stone statue). Across the way was a glyph (shows the person going down the mountain). I floated down under the water a bit and when I saw above last ancient glyphs there were 6 grave stones with 3 grave stones on either side. I called out here and the camera view changed and pointed to something and the water went down a section.

What happened? Is this a glitch or a secret? I can't finish this level (since I can't get back to the top). UPDATE With the help of the last couple cloth creatures I had just enough scarf to fly up. Now I'm at the top again (water is still receded).

Also, while I was a section below I went to a neighboring ancient glyph and when I call out the lights glow and then fade out. Only one of the glyphs has done this. It makes me think that something might happen if I had a companion call out at the same time.

UPDATE - the neighboring glyph is to the left and down from the first ancient glyph I mention at the beginning of this post (that started it all). It is just under the water and in the first major left column. It ALSO has the 6 gravestones in the middle with 3 on either side. It doesn't have any lit up story on it. I swam to the left and the ancient glyph that's a neighbor to this one does have lit up story.

NOTE: I couldn't reproduce it the second time. I think it had to do with a companion activated the last ancient glyph, then they left. Then I went down to the glyph and was able to activate it again (bug).

In any case I'm still able to go to the neighbor ancient glyph, call out and the grave stone glow like they are going to do something.

Comment: Take a picture?

Comment: Will do next chance I get